# Placement of Login code to website using Facebook account

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Hi I'm new to web development. I would like to code for Login to website using Facebook account which I know that I need to add this js to install the Facebook SDK:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-app-id',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

However, I'm unsure on where to put it. It was mentioned that I should insert it directly after the opening `<body>` tag on each page I want to load it. However, Both of my register and login.php were done in floating div. There's no `<body>` tag. Hence, I not sure where to add this code in too:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{ 
    session_start(); 
}

require_once('config.php');
require_once('facebook.php');
require_once('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$fbUser = $facebook->getUser();

$_SESSION[$PROJECT_NAME . '-allowUser'] = true;

$uri = explode('/', strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'?'));

if ($fbUser) {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $fbEmail = $user_profile["email"];
    $fbId = $user_profile["id"];
}
```

Below is my login.php.

**login.php**

```
<div id="loginScreen">
<div class="xclose">
    <a href="#" class="cancel"><em>&times;</em></a>
</div>

<a href="<?php echo $base_url; ?>loginFb"><div id="loghead">Facebook Connect</div></a>
<div class="articlepreview">
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" id="registrationForm"
        action="processLogin">
        <div class="signintitle">Sign in to your Account</div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="emailaddr" type="email" name="emailaddr" required
                id="emailaddr" placeholder="Email Address"> <br> <input
                type="password" name="password" required class="password"
                id="id_password" placeholder=Password
                <?php
                if (preg_match ( "/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/", $password )) {
                    echo "Your passwords is strong.";
                } else {
                    echo "Your password is weak.";
                }
                ?>
                required>
        </div>

        <br>
        <center>
            <input class="greybtn" type="submit" value="Sign in" name="signin">
        </center>

        <div class="forgotpw" style="text-align: center;">
            <br> <a href="/sggrocer/resetpassword">Forgot Password?</a> <br>
            <a href="#regScreen">Create an Account</a> <br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```